# JScrollPane Isn't Working Inside JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

In my Java program, which I have made by following a tutorial, there is a class in which I create a JSplitPane, and inside that I put a JList embedded in a JScrollPane and a JTextArea below that. The problem is, whenever I add enough items to the JList so that you cannot see all of them because the list is relatively small, the scroll bar does not appear on the right side of the list. This could be because I am nesting that split pane in another split pane, but it seems to be working fine in the tutorials that I am watching, so I'm wondering what's wrong. Here is the code that I use to create that particular JSplitPane:

```
lowerPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, new JScrollPane(messages), textPanel);
```

As you can see, I have carefully embedded the messages component, which is a JList, inside a JScrollPane. However, the scroll bar does not appear in my program when the JList is filled up. Here is a picture of my program:

[image: My Application]

The application may be hard to understand, even though I know it is very basic coding. What I'm really concerned with is the JScrollPane. In the window where it lists the titles of the received messages, you can see no scroll bar.

Comment: Have you used `setPreferredSize`?

Comment: No, I don't think I have, but I'll check!

Comment: Actually, yes, I have, but it's also not working because the component stays the same size even if I set a minimum size on it

Comment: Consider providing a [**runnable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Since I don't really care if anyone downloads this application, here is a site where you can download it and try it:

Comment: The site is: mycode.pbworks.com

Comment: Go to the tab labelled Messages and tick some of the tree nodes in the tree and make the checkboxes checked until the JList is filled up and you will see that there is no scroll bar appearing.

Comment: I think you'll need to do something about a viewport for your scrollpane if you want it to occupy the full space.

Comment: `Actually, yes, I have,` - Well, I have no idea what "preferred size" either of your are talking about.  However, you should NOT be setting a preferred size on the JList. If you do set a preferred size then the scroll pane won't work properly. Also, we are not interested in your application. You need to provide a simple program demonstrating what you are doing. So all you need is a JFrame with a split pane. Then one part of the split pane should contain your scroll pane and JList. The total program should be 20-25 lines of code. I'm sure if you do this you will find your problem.

Comment: I just set a size on the scroll pane instead and that solved my problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @James, `I just set a size on the scroll pane instead`, no, don't set a size on anything. Its the job of the layout manager to determine the size of a component. You can use the `JList.setVisibleRowCount(...)` method to suggest an initial size for the JList. This will help determine the size when the frame is "packed". The real size will be determined by the space available in the split pane.